# Angular test throwError

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am having some difficulties making a test in angular.

I have a function in a service that goes like this:

```
 public getConfigFromData(conf: string, data: any): Observable<any> {
    if (!conf) {
      return throwError(`Error`);
    } else if (data) {
      return this.getConfig(conf, data);
    } else {
      return throwError('Other error');
    }
  }
```

And I'm having some problems when testing the error thrown.
This is the following test:

```
it('...', () => {
    expect(() => {
      service.getConfigFromData(null, '');
    }).toThrowError('Error');
  });
```

The error that I get from jasmine is

> Error: Expected function to throw an Error.

I've been trying to find in other answers but couldn't obtain any conclusion.
Can anyone guess what I am missing or doing wrong?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The posted method is `getConfigFromData` but in the test, you invoke `getConfigFromContext`.

Comment: @uminder completely agree but that was my mistake copying :) I have edited it thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `throwError` returns an observable and you need to `subscribe` to the method for the observable to take flight.

Try this:

```
it('...', (done: DoneFn) => {
      service.getConfigFromContext(null, '').pipe(take(1)).subscribe({
      next: () => {},
      // subscribe, make assertion in the error block and call done to
      // let jasmine know you're done with the unit test
      error: (error) => { expect(error).toBeTruthy(); done(); }
   });

  });
```

I think `.toThrowError` is for regular JavaScript of `throw new Error('error');`.

Comment: Oh ok, I see, thank you so much for your fast response. I've implemented it and works like charms. I  understand it now :)

Answer (score 1):

The returned `throwError` is an `Observable` of type `Observable<never>` that will error with the specified error immediately upon subscription. Hence, to make your test work, you would have to subscribe to the `Observable` or may simply transform it to a `Promise` to see the error be thrown. This can be done using  `async`/`await` as follows:

```
it('#getConfigFromData should throw Error', async () => {
  try {
     await getConfigFromData(null, '').toPromise().then(() => null);
     fail('should have thrown Error')
  } catch (error) {
     expect(error).toBe('Error')
  }
});
```